# Hypothesis Tests: Finding size and power for various decision rules

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I have a homework question as follows, so would appreciate hints and suggestions.

Given two uniform i.i.d. random variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$, with support $[\theta ;\theta +1]$. The hypotheses are as follows - $H_0: \theta = 0$ ; $H_A: \theta \neq 0$.

Part of the assignment is to determine the size and power of a test which always rejects $H_0$ regardless of observed data, and a test which always accepts $H_0$ regardless of observed data.

How do we think about the power of a test in cases like this, where we're not thinking about Z scores or any clearly defined probabilities?

Comment: What do you mean by the "size" of a hypothesis test?

Comment: @Matthew By "size", I mean the probability of falsely rejecting the null hypothesis.

Comment: Also, the power of a hypothesis test is the probability of rejecting a false $H_0$. That being said, if you're always accepting $H_0$ regardless of observed data, then in this case the power of your test is necessarily equal to zero.

Comment: So the term "size" in your class means the probability of rejecting a true null hypothesis, right? That is usually called "significance" and is denoted by $\alpha$

Comment: In the first test, if you always rejecting the null, what is your (conditional) probability of rejecting the null (given the null is true / false)? Similar for the other question.

Comment: 'Size' is standard terminology for probability of rejecting true $H_0.$ If always reject $H_0$ then size $\alpha=1$ and power is $0.$ Ponder why that's true and you can answer the other part.

Comment: There is a difference between the size and the level of significance. They might be equal in many cases but not always. See for example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/51217/128491

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an analogy from a completely different every day scenario that you might want to think about. Consider two decision rules:

A) Tag someone as having a fever regardless of their temperature.

B) Tag someone as not having a fever regardless of their temperature.

In the scenario of a person truly having a fever, decision rule A will be absolutely perfect.

In the scenario of a person truly not having a fever, decision rule B will be absolutely perfect.